# pandas read_csv with date object

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file which looks like [my csv file looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiR83.png)

For example, the `"(2011/07/21 -1.0000 $, 2011/08/21 -1.0000 $)"` this value should all be in the column `Expiry`, excel shows them in columns `Expiry` and `Currency` because of the comma separator.

Now I want to read this csv file into python, and it gives me trouble due to that comma separator thing. Is there any way I can read it so that the ideal dataframe will look like [ideal format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkCHB.png)

So it's like whenever there is a `"whatever inside"`, then treat the thing inside `""` as a whole, and put them in one column, otherwise split by `comma+space`.

Thanks.

Comment: Will the `,` you want to ignore always be preceded by a literal `$`?

Comment: @rahlf23 Yes it is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do this would be to:

```
df = pd.read_csv('nonideal.csv', quotechar='"')
```

In this case strings with "" quotes around them will be treated as total, even if commas are inside.

Output with your practice data:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('./Desktop/df1.csv', quotechar='"')
>>> df
   units  one                                    expiry  currency  amount
0    100    0  "(2011/07/21-1.000$, 2011/08/21-1.000$)"       100       0
1      0   20  "(2011/07/21-1.000$, 2011/08/21-1.000$)"         0      30
```

Comment: I think you mean `quotechar='"'`. Apart from that, this is the correct solution

Answer (score 1):

If the `,` you want to ignore will always be preceded by a literal `$`, then you can do the following using a negative lookbehind:

```
pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', sep=r'(?<!\$),\s')
```

You can see the regex in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/HiS62g/2/).

Comment: This solution is not ideal because the separator for this file is actually a comma, and the quotes are used for grouping. Using this kind of regexp is asking for trouble once you get more complex datasets.

Comment: I agree that this is not the **ideal solution**, however for this minimal use case, I figured I would throw it out there. @d_kennetz answer is definitely the preferred solution.